# populating SMS message in android

Tags: java, android, sms

Here is the code snippet from our app now.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" ));
    sms.putExtra("sms_body", text);
    startActivity(sms);
}
```

This works with the stock SMS app, however a tester reported that with handcent SMS they get a blank message.  This prompted me to try it with Google Voice, also get a blank message there.

Is there some way I can get my message text to work with all of these other SMS apps?

We have a clipboard functionality, so a poor workaround at least would be having user push clipboard button, then use their messaging app of choice.

Comment: Ali, I don't understand your question.  The app builds a text to send based on different variables, then has intent to send message.

Comment: you can send your sms directly from your activity without any need to open another Activity. `SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("phoneNumber", null, "Sms Body", null, null);` Don't forget to set permission in AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

Comment: Ok, but what about selecting the to address?  Also, the user might want to customize the message that is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Android tries to reuse Intents as much as possible. In some cases when you start an intent, android doesn't create a new Intent and reuse previous intents. To avoid this set this flag of Intent:

```
smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This flag forces Android to create a new Task with the intent's Activity on top of stack.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass this intent , this will be delivered to all those apps which have registered an activity to receive it. In otherwords you have to use the intent that is registered by the application that u intent to handle your intent